# Pagination is not correct when I apply a sticky posts

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

For my pagination, I am using **get_the_posts_pagination()**

This is my pagination code:

```
<div class="the-categories">

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


<div class="page-nation">
    <ul id="Pagination" class="pagination pagination-large">
    <?php 
        $pagination = get_the_posts_pagination(array(
            'mid_size'  => 2,
            'prev_text' =>esc_html__('Previous', 'travel-tour'),
            'next_text' => esc_html__('Next', 'travel-tour'),
            'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
        ) );
        echo $pagination;
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I have added this function to my functions.php to the purpose of calculating the posts display on page.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ad_custom_query');
function ad_custom_query($query) {

    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {

        // set the number of posts per page
        $posts_per_page = 6;
        // get sticky posts array
        $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

        // if we have any sticky posts and we are at the first page
        if (is_array($sticky_posts) && !$query->is_paged()) {

            // counnt the number of sticky posts
            $sticky_count = count($sticky_posts);

            // and if the number of sticky posts is less than
            // the number we want to set:
            if ($sticky_count < $posts_per_page) {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page - $sticky_count);

            // if the number of sticky posts is greater than or equal
            // the number of pages we want to set:
            } else {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
            }

        // fallback in case we have no sticky posts
        // and we are not on the first page
        } else {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
        }
    }
}
```

all is working except for the pagination, on my current page it should be 4 pages for the pagination but when I add a sticky post it goes to 5 pages and the last one leads to a 404

Comment: this question already answer given please follow this links https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20314/pagination-with-sticky-posts

Comment: Hi Anand Choudhary, but that anser is not working on pagination :-(

Comment: kindly follow this links https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180005/include-sticky-post-in-page-posts-count/180021#180021

Comment: Hi I have tried that but it only works for 1 stick post, if I add multiple it breaks the pagination, sorry for the hassle...